# Problem in First soapUI Project

Tags: automated-testing, soapui

I have downloaded SoapUI trial from [SoapUI site](http://soapui.org/),

- went to the following page:
  http://www.soapui.org/Getting-Started/your-first-soapui-project.html
- created a soapUI project;
- added following WSDL:
  http://www.mobilefish.com/services/web_service/countries.php?wsdl

and when I click ok I get the following error:

> Error loading
>   [http://www.mobilefish.com/services/web_service/countries.php?wsdl]:
>   org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException:
>   error: Unexpected end of file after null

Can anybody please help me to sort out this error?

Comment: Most of the public webservices used in these posts have disappeared or no longer work. There is on list on YouTube - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v2aNSUZtFRY&t=1s

Answer (score 5):

The link for the WSDL appears to be invalid.

Try using a different WSDL e.g. http://dic.googlecode.com/files/GoogleSearch.wsdl

Answer (score 3):

This is what I found from the [Mobilefish quick guide](http://www.mobilefish.com/tutorials/web_service/web_service_quickguide_countries.html):

> The Countries web service is permanently disabled because this service is being misused.

Answer (score 2):

It seems Countries WSDL path is wrong.

You can try TempConvert Wsdl as an example in W3Schools Web site:

http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?wsdl

When you load the wsdl from SoapUI tool you will see 2 operations belongs to this web service:

- CelciusToFahrenheit
- FahrenheitToCelsius